# error connecting to oracle database. ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, tnsnames

I have a `SAP` database deployed on a `Linux` server with `Oracle 10g` installed on it. I tried to connect to this database from Windows 8 computer using `Oracle SQL Developer`. Oracle 11.2.0 is installed on this Windows 8 computer. I am connecting using the following `TNS` entry in `tnsnames.ora` file

```
SAPTRN =
(DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.x.xx)(PORT = 1527))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = TRN))
)
```

I am able to connect successfully and can browse SAP tables as required.

Now I want to connect to the same database on the same computer using Visual studio's Add new Connection dialog. But I get below error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `tnsnames.ora` file located?

- Create/verify Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`, it must point to folder of your `tnsnames.ora` file.
- Create/verify Registry key

  `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`

  resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`

  they must point to folder of your `tnsnames.ora` file